# Enum is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I have enum:

```
export enum Roles {
  user = 10,
  editor = 30,
  admin = 50,
}
```

I import it to one of my services:

```
import { Roles } from '../enums/roles';
```

And use in service method:

```
  this.writeRole(
    Roles.user,
  );
```

And when i call this method in my app, in console i got error: `Cannot read property 'user' of undefined`

But when i simply write the same enum (but without `export` keyword) in service instead of import, its work perfect. Please, explain, what i did wrong and why i can not just import enum like classes?

Comment: You most likely don't import your enum from the right place. Are you sure about the location of your enum ?

Comment: @trichetriche absolutely, import path even autocompleted by ide

Comment: Some IDE (I'm looking at you VSCode) don't import from the correct path when you have moved your files : you need to rebuild the index, which you do by pressing F1 and entering "reload" to reload the window.

Comment: And is your error in AOT only, or do you have it when serving ?

Comment: @trichetriche you was right, its was VSC bug

Comment: I know, I'm always tricked by that :D I'm making an answer to close your question !

Comment: @trichetriche I almost went crazy trying to figure out what the problem is :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is usually bound to your IDE : let's take for instance Visual studio code (I'm using it and apparently you do too)

When you create a file, VSCode adds it to its index. It allows you to CtrlP to open a file.

But when you move it, VSCode doesn't rebuild its index. This means it imports your file from a wrong location.

It will detect it as defined, won't throw any error (because to him, his index is up to date), but at compilation time the issue will pop.

To avoid that, you can either rebuild the index by reloading VSCode (close it, or hit the command shortcut (F1) and type "reload"), or you can use a plugin such as **[Move Typescript](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stringham.move-ts)**, which is very useful for moving files.

Answer (score 1):

In your service / component - just do "enum = Enum":

```
roles = Roles
```